# How to receive data from server using Kotlin?

Tags: python, android, sockets, kotlin, client-server

I have a server written in python and an Android client written in Kotlin (in Android Studio IDE). I use sockets for maintaining this connection. After the client sends a message to the server, the server will need to send an answer to the  client. I didn't find a way to receive data at the client by using sockets. I tried to do that:

```
var server = Socket(serverIP, serverPort)
server.outputStream.write(message.toByteArray())
var answer = server.inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
server.close()
```

but it seems not to work. If it matters, the sending at server side looks like that:

```
client.send(message.encode())
```

Comment: You leave a lot to our imagination. What is `message`? And what is in it? And what type of encoding? And what is finally send?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are using OkHttp for this. In my app I have the following code

```
private fun getClient(): OkHttpClient {
    return try {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.pingInterval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        builder.build()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
}

class WebSocketController(
    val callback: SomeCallback
) {
    private val url = "wss://your.url.com/"

    private val socketClient = getClient()
    private var serverSocket: WebSocket? = null

    private val listener = object : WebSocketListener() {
        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            super.onOpen(webSocket, response)

            val json = "" // your payload to send on connect
            serverSocket = webSocket
            serverSocket!!.send(json)
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
            val data = Json.decodeFromString<YourModel>(text)

            // here you can use your data from server
            callback.makeSomething(data)
        }

        override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
            super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
            callback.onFailure(t)
        }
    }

    fun establishConnection() {
        socketClient.newWebSocket(requestBuilder().build(), listener)
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        val json = "" // your payload on disconnect
        serverSocket?.send(json)
    }

    private fun requestBuilder(): Request.Builder = Request.Builder().url(url)
}
```